# Cancel jobs running on the same partition on SLURM

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, slurm

with the commands

```
$>squeue -u mnyber004
```

I can visualize all the submitted jobs on my cluster account (slurm)

```
          JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
         16884       ada   CPUeq6 mnyber00  R 1-01:26:17      1 srvcnthpc105
         16882       ada   CPUeq4 mnyber00  R 1-01:26:20      1 srvcnthpc104
         16878       ada   CPUeq2 mnyber00  R 1-01:26:31      1 srvcnthpc104
         20126       ada   CPUeq1 mnyber00  R   22:32:28      1 srvcnthpc103
         22004     curie WRI_0015 mnyber00  R      16:11      1 srvcnthpc603
         22002     curie WRI_0014 mnyber00  R      16:13      1 srvcnthpc603
         22000     curie WRI_0013 mnyber00  R      16:14      1 srvcnthpc603
```

How to cancel all the jobs running on the partition `ada`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `scancel` offers the appropriate filters, so you can simply run

```
scancel -u mnyber004 -p ada
```

Should it not have been the case, a frequent idiom is to use the more powerful filtering properties of `squeue` and the `--format` option to build the proper command and then feed it to `sh`:

```
squeue -u mnyber004 -p ada --format "scancel %i" | sh
```

You can play it safer by first saving to a file and then sourcing the file.

```
squeue -u mnyber004 -p ada --format "scancel %j" > /tmp/remove.sh
source remove.sh
```